# Requests não esta sendo enviado com o payload em Python - Moodle

Tags: python, web-service, moodle, python-requests

Boa tarde,

Estou com um problema que já esta dando uma certa dor de cabeça. O bendito payload da requisição não esta sendo enviado para o webservice, somente a url.

Meu código está assim:

```
class Curso:
'''Resgata todas as disciplinas modelo'''
def getDisModelo(self):

    config = Config()

    serverUrlDisc = config.dominio + "/webservice/rest/server.php" + "?wstoken=" + \
                    config.alocaGrupoToken + "&wsfunction=" + "core_course_get_courses_by_field" \
                    + "&moodlewsrestformat=" + config.formatoRest

    params = json.dumps({'field': 'id', 'value': '31198'})

    s = requests.session()
    s.verify=False

    response = s.post(serverUrlDisc, data=params)
    disciplinasAva = response.json()
    response.status_code

    return disciplinasAva
```

O que acontece, eu consigo enviar a requisição porém ele não reconhece o conteúdo de params de jeito nenhum, ou seja, só é enviado a url e os parametros não. Alguém sabe o porque isto esta ocorrendo? Minha versão do Python é 3.7

Answer (score -1):

Se você usar o `data=` para enviar seus parâmetros, junto com uma string, no caso, o JSON codificado, o conteúdo é enviado de forma "bruta" no corpo da requisição HTTP. Se o servidor não estiver esperando uma resposta JSON, que pode vir, nesse caso, com os cabeçalhos incorretos, não vai funcionar mesmo.

Se o servidor aceitar JSON, em vez de chamar um `json.dumps` com seus dados, passe-os diretamente no parâmetro `json=` na chamada do méto post. Isso não só vai codificar os dados, mas vai colocar os cabeçalhos corretos:

```
...
params = {'field': 'id', 'value': '31198'}

s = requests.session()
s.verify=False

response = s.post(serverUrlDisc, json=params)
...
```

Agora, se a aplicação no servidor não está esperando JSON, e sim, os dados codificados como form-encoded, nesse caso, você passa os dados na forma de dicionário direto no parâmetro `data=`, sem serializar o JSON antes:

```
...
params = {'field': 'id', 'value': '31198'}

s = requests.session()
s.verify=False

response = s.post(serverUrlDisc, data=params)
...
```

Comment: já tentei esses dois métodos previamente, mas sem sucesso. Acredito que seja o servidor Moodle que esta barrando o payload em json. Preciso achar o local para alterar essa configuração.